# Массив элементов

Tags: массивы, объекты, javascript

Приветствую!
Пытаюсь сделать конструкцию вида *$('.myclass li a');* - должно вернуть все элементы с тегами *a*. 
Остановился на этом моменте..

```
var $ = function(e) {
var getElement = function(e,el){
var el = (el)?el:document;
if(e.charAt(0) == '.')
{
var __e = el.getElementsByClassName(e.substring(1));
}
else if(e.charAt(0) == '#')
{
var __e = el.getElementById(e.substring(1));
}
else
{
var __e = el.getElementsByTagName(e);
}
return __e;
};
element = [];
var e = e.split(' ');
for(var i in e)
{
var _e = getElement(e[i],element[(element.length-1)]);
element.push(_e);
}
return _e;
}
```

Comment: @Cript, вы намеренно пытаетесь воспроизвести sizzle (компонете jquery)?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, там по-другому